# Error starting up sts/luna with MavenBuilder and Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-luna

I recently upgraded my Eclipse to STS 3.6.3, which is Eclipse Luna under the covers.

I started it up with the same workspace I used with my Kepler Eclipse instance.

I see a few problems after startup.

The first thing is an error dialog with the following contents:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Error instantiating builder 'org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder'.
>   Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core (576).

I checked the log, and found the following hopefully relevant stacktrace:

> ```
> !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-01-15 06:50:18.992
> !MESSAGE Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.
> !STACK 0
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core (576).
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:320)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:391)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
>     at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.m2e.M2EUtils.createImplementation(M2EUtils.java:172)
>     at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.m2e.M2EUtils.implementation(M2EUtils.java:165)
>     at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.m2e.M2EUtils.isInstalled(M2EUtils.java:183)
>     at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.classpathcontainer.GradleClassPathContainer.ensureOpenCloseListener(GradleClassPathContainer.java:193)
>     at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.classpathcontainer.GradleClassPathContainer.getClasspathEntries(GradleClassPathContainer.java:152)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.containerPutIfInitializingWithSameEntries(JavaModelManager.java:667)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SetContainerOperation.executeOperation(SetContainerOperation.java:49)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:789)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1942)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3247)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2697)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2861)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClasspathChange.generateDelta(ClasspathChange.java:221)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessor.java:2065)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessingState.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessingState.java:477)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:378)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1498)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1718)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob.runInWorkspace(RefreshJob.java:167)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
> Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     ... 37 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext does not implement the requested interface org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
>     at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.<init>(MavenPluginActivator.java:88)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
>     ... 40 more
> ```

When I select "Update Project" from the Maven section of the context menu, it gives me a dialog saying "The chosen operation is not currently available".

Comment: It looks like an api incompatibility between m2e and logback packages. This causes m2e bundles not to be properly loaded (error is happening during bundle initialization of m2e.core). Maybe try upgrading m2e to latest version. If that doesn't work try a fresh install of STS 3.6.3 instead of upgrading your old one.

Comment: I almost always have everything at the latest version. This was a fresh install of STS.  I reused the older workspace, not the Eclipse/STS distribution.

Comment: I don't think you get this problem from the old workspace (looks like incompatible bundles, not workspace issue), but it doesn't hurt to try and open a fresh workspace. If you are getting this problem with an 'out of the box' (or close) STS then it could be a problem in the stuff we packaged together. If you can reproduce it and tell us steps how to put the stuff you have together, please file a bug report, or post more details here and I'll try to reproduce it)

Comment: Quickly add some info: good way to get 'all the details' of your installation is menu "Help >> Installation Details" on the "Configuration" tab is a whole bunch of text that has 'all the details' we wanna know (and more :-)